# 20.04 sudden loss of wired Internet causes no mouse and keyboard control

Tags: keyboard, mouse, internet

Everything will be working fine, until a random loss of wired Internet will occur immediately followed by loss of mouse and keyboard control. So far the only solution is to reboot using my pc's power button. Using a dual boot system with Windows 10 on a separate SSD.

Comment: How does it work with Windows 10?

Comment: Without a problem, Windows functions exactly as it used to. I've had Ubuntu for just over a week and this has only started happening today.

Comment: Please edit the question and post hardware specifications so we can start to think about possible issues.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to disable automatic screen locking, I'm feeling dumb for missing it on my initial setup

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Do you mean to say the "automatic screen locking" was doing its job and you mistook it to be a problem? Or do you mean to to say the screen lock was not working properly? If the second, you may want to ask a new question.